# how to upload a file using libcurl in c

Tags: c, file-upload, curl, libcurl

I am building an application and I want it to upload a file using http
. I am doing this using libcurl.  I would like someone to give an example on how to upload a file, either in c using lib curl. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fileupload.html

Comment: @larsmans - You should probably post that as an answer so it can be accepted, IMO

Comment: possible duplicate of [saving a file using open dialog box in c with libcurl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248912/saving-a-file-using-open-dialog-box-in-c-with-libcurl)

Comment: @Neil: that question is about "saving a file from a remote url", i.e. downloading. This one's about uploading.

Comment: uploading a file with HTTP is not very exact. You can upload files using several different ways with HTTP and while libcurl can do them it is hard to tell a specific answer unless the question is more precise.

Answer (score 1):

See the file upload example in the cURL docs and change the protocol from `file` to whatever you want to use: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fileupload.html. Note that [`CURLOPT_UPLOAD`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTUPLOAD) will send a `PUT` request when doing HTTP.

Or check out the FTP upload example: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpupload.html